# Adding a tikz picture to every slide in a beamer presenation

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, macros, slideshow

I have a tikz drawing I would like to add to every slide in my beamer presentation. Presenly I have to add it manually to every slide - a bit tedious! Is there a way of using a `\newcommand` to do this automatically?

The code for the tikz image is :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
     \draw [line width=2mm,MyColor] (current page.south east) rectangle (current page.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Cheers!

Comment: You could define your picture as a logo and see in the Beamer manual or in examples how logos are used.

Comment: @DRi I tried that. I added a `\logo` in front of the above code, but it just failed to compile.

Comment: Besides, you should use a beamer theme which requires a logo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mind if it's covered by other text, you can place the picture into the `background` template.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usebackgroundtemplate{
    \tikz \draw[line width=2mm, red] ([shift={(1mm,1mm)}]current page.south west) rectangle ([shift={(-1mm,-1mm)}]current page.north east);}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\logo{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \draw [line width=2mm,black] (current page.south east) rectangle (current page.north west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        abc
    \end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: @QuantumPenguin You are welcome. But if you are really using this to add a frame, you should take Ignasi's answer.